# Animation: jQuery or Raphael?

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, raphael

I am building a page that will animate objects (image/shape/div) and float them around the screen.  At times there may be a large number of objects floating and interacting.

A requirement is to have data associated with each object, as they will each have an id.  So, if I click one object, it can grab that ID, then reference an array that holds the data about that object.

My debate is, if I should use the jQuery $.animate function or use Raphael.  I know that SVG would be nice to use, but I am unsure if I can give each object and id, then bring up a div containing associated data onclick.  Can clicking SVG elements reference DOM elements?  How well does SVG work with dynamic text?  I am also concerned about how much processing power the animation will take.  Is there a better choice in this regard?

BTW, I am no talking about jQuery SVG here, just normal jQuery and DOM.

If anyone has any insight into this, or suggestions they would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just as a quick note - this is possible with HTML5 and canvas (click on any dot): http://9elements.com/io/projects/html5/canvas/

Comment: Also, canvas tends to be faster being that it is basically a thin layer over the OS drawing API.  However, canvas is not as fully exposed to the DOM as SVG.

Comment: @ fudgey - Yeah, I have seen that demo.  I really don't think that the comment that comes up on click actually has anything to do with the dot you click.  They are just chosen at random, rather than assigned to a dot.  Pretty sure this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About speedy jQuery animations, you may be interested in this : http://code.zemanta.com/fry/ruleanimation/

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  All graphical objects are added as DOM objects.

A demo: http://raphaeljs.com/github/impact.html

simple demo code that draws a circle, assigns an id, and attaches an onclick event:

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
// Creates circle at x = 50, y = 40, with radius 10
var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
// Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
// Sets the stroke attribute of the circle to white (#fff)
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");
//assign circle id="lolcats"
circle.node.id="lolcats";
//onclick alert id
circle.node.onclick=function(){alert(this.id)};
```

If you need to do fancy vector drawing and manipulations, Raphael would be good.  If not, you might as well just use what you know.  Also, you can use both jQuery and Raphael at the same time.
From the sounds of it though, jQuery should be plenty enough for your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I am not really needing to do vector drawings. Right now I am mostly concerned about speed, and how many objects I could have on the screen. And, based on that which would be my best solution.

For now, I will just stick with jQuery and see if I run into any limitations.

Thanks.